# Comment out proof in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals

I would like to comment out my proof conditionally. I tried to use the following but it didn't work.

`\usepackage{comment}` didn't work, because I use `\documentclass{elegantbook}` they are not compatible.

```
\newif\ifanswers

%\answerstrue  % comment out to hide answers

\answersfalse % comment out to show answers

\documentclass{amsart}

\newenvironment{sol}{\ifanswers\begin{proof}}{\end{proof}\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{sol}

abc

\end{sol}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please show a full (minimal) document from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`? As far as I can understand this is not related to `beamer`, is it?